# Can't disable popup blocking on chrome ruby + watir webdriver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir-webdriver

I can't disable popup blocking on chrome, using ruby with watir webdriver.

I tried this:

```
profile['profile.default_content_settings.popups'] = 0
```

but popup is still blocked.
What's wrong?

Comment: I find solution, just use chromeOptions:

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome

caps["chromeOptions"] = {}

caps["chromeOptions"]["args"] = ["--disable-popup-blocking"]

Comment: In order to answer your own question, you don't need to write a comment. Please read [the following article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to know how you can answer your own question.